# clonezilla shell: update-initramfs is disabled, do i need to chroot and How? (External SSD)

Tags: usb, chroot, ssd, clonezilla

I want to clone my laptop to an External HDD.

I need to make an important precision: the process is successfull when i'm using mecanic HDD (old laptop).

i use clonezilla to clone
i go to clonezilla shell and make changes.

i'm able to have 2 functionnal systems (first is into my laptop HDD, second is into my external HDD)

I want to make same but with 2 SSDs (first into my new laptop, second is an External SSD)

Here the process (with mecanic and SSD)

- changing external SSD partitions UUIDs
- changing external SSD partitions PARTUUIDs
- changing external SSD /boot/grub/grub.cfg
- changing external SSD /etc/fstab
- changing external SSD /etc/default/grub
- changing external SSD /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
- changing INTERNAL SSD /etc/default/grub
- changing external SSD /boot/efi/EFI/debian/grub.cfg
- define new  external SSD GUID

ok, now, the following is ok with mecanic HDDs but not with SSDs

- chroot
- inside chroot: update-initramfs -c -k all
- inside chroot: update-grub /dev/sda

i reboot, i'have the choice, i can boot with internal or external HDD

with SSDs

- chroot
- inside chroot: update-initramfs -c -k all returns

update-initramfs is disabled (live system is running without media mounted on /run/live/medium)

following, commands to chroot

```
    mount -o bind /dev /media/${utilisateur}/${uuid_racine_sda2}/dev

    mount -o bind /sys /media/${utilisateur}/${uuid_racine_sda2}/sys

    mount -o bind /proc /media/${utilisateur}/${uuid_racine_sda2}/proc

    chroot /media/${utilisateur}/${uuid_racine_sda2}
    
    umount /media/${utilisateur}/${uuid_racine_sda2}/proc
    umount /media/${utilisateur}/${uuid_racine_sda2}/sys
    umount /media/${utilisateur}/${uuid_racine_sda2}/dev
    
    umount /media/${utilisateur}/${uuid_racine_sda2}
    rmdir /media/${utilisateur}/${uuid_racine_sda2}
```

Sorry for repeating,

this is working with mecanic HDDs but not with SSD HDDs

So i need to change something, i think the way of chrooting but i don't know next commands.

any advices to solve the return of "initramfs is disabled..." or to help me to make a good chroot please.

os-prober detects 2 system, it's ok with that

Thank you

Comment: I don't see you mounting the whole disk anywhere in the script, so where are you chrooting exactly?

Comment: well, as i said, this is working as this with mecanic HDDs, but after reading your comment, i saw some examples and yes i have to make folders first to chroot. i need to make attempts with. i will come back to tell you after another tests. Thks for your notice (is this the good word?)

Comment: ok, attempts done, "it seems" to work when i create folders to chroot... i'm a real dummy. sorry for this question (more attemts tomorrow). Anyway, thanks for your answer